# Recovery of existing ZFS pool after clean server install of 18.04 LTS

Tags: server, upgrade, zfs

I have an existing 16.04 LTS server with an O/S HDD and separate drives in the ZFS pool. I want to do a clean install of 18.04.1 LTS once it becomes avaialble rather than an upgrade and my question is will the ZFS pool still be recoverable post migration with all data intact?

Answer (score 3):

You can export the ZFS pool and then import it once you complete your reinstall with the new OS version.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbchy/index.html